# Heroku: Can I have one app pointing to myapp.com/ and another app to myapp.com/something?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I'd like to have one app pointing to myapp.com/ and another app to myapp.com/something?

Is this possible ANd legal?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tried it, but here are some ideas centered around Rack:

http://docs.heroku.com/rack

http://asciicasts.com/episodes/222-rack-in-rails-3

http://blog.yasserdahab.com/post/207166942/application-mashing-with-rails-sinatra-rack